# Python - argparse require either or

Tags: python

When you run the script, you have to pass either `-g` or `-s`. With the code below, it throws the following error with the argument(s) passed to it.

```
{~/nsnitro}-> ./sg-arg.py status -g test.server
usage: sg-arg.py [-h] (-g SERVICEGROUP | -s SERVICENAME) {status} ...
sg-arg.py: error: one of the arguments -g/--servicegroup -s/--servicename is required
```

Code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

check = subparsers.add_parser('status')
check = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
check.add_argument('-g', '--servicegroup', action='store', help='servicegroup name', type=servicegroup_status)
check.add_argument('-s', '--servicename', action='store', help='service name', type=servicegroup_status)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: It appears that you're adding the mutually exclusive group the to master parser, not the subparser.  e.g. `./sg-arg.py -g test.server status` would be the correct call in this case I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the mutually exclusive group to the wrong parser.  In other words, with the call you have, the correct call would be something like `./sg-arg.py -g test.server status` (notice the argument comes *before* the subparser declaration).

To fix it, you'd add the mutual exclusion group to the subparser and add the arguments to that group.  This seems to work:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

check = subparsers.add_parser('status')
check_mutex = check.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
check_mutex.add_argument('-g', '--servicegroup', action='store', help='servicegroup name')
check_mutex.add_argument('-s', '--servicename', action='store', help='service name')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

e.g.

```
$ python foo.py status -g test.server
$ python foo.py status -s test.server
$ python foo.py status  test.server
usage: foo.py status [-h] (-g SERVICEGROUP | -s SERVICENAME)
foo.py status: error: one of the arguments -g/--servicegroup -s/--servicename is required
```

Comment: Ah I see, so removing `type=servicegroup_status` breaks the code. I'm actually calling a function called `servicegroup_status` and passing in the arguments. The script runs fine, but the function doesn't get called.

Comment: Ok I take it back, the function gets executed but it still throws the error when I add `type=FUNCTION_NAME` `sg-arg.py status: error: one of the arguments -g/--servicegroup -s/--servicename is required`